# How to show file is being uploaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have working code to store an image in memory before posting to an API.
However it can take some time to load that file into memory. I need a way to show that the file is being loaded.

I have a spinner icon that I can show using ng-show, but I don't have anything that I can set the ng-show to. So far nothing I've found provides a simple solution. Is there an HTML5 or angular way to do this without being too complicated?

HTML:

```
<input  class="input-dnld" id="loadImg" type='file' placeholder="Select an image to upload"  name="topoImg" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().readimg(this)" accept="image/*" required>
<label for="loadImg" required><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open glyph-style"></span>Select an image to upload</label>
```

JS:

```
$scope.readimg = function(ele) {
    $scope.image = ele.files[0];
}
```

Comment: At the risk of belaboring the obvious, can't you set a variable at the beginning of `readImg` and change the value before you exit?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It wasn't that the code in readimg didn't get run or that the flags I added later didn't get set, but rather that the bindings were not updating until after it had returned.

Here is my quick fix:

```
$scope.readimg = function(ele) {
  $scope.imgupload = true;
  $scope.$apply()
  $scope.image = ele.files[0];
  $scope.imgupload = false;
  $scope.$apply()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a FileReader object (using your comment, with minor change):

```
$scope.readimg = function(ele) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onloadend = function (e) {
        $scope.image = e.target.result;
        ele.imgupload = false;
    }
    ele.imgupload = true;
    r.readAsArrayBuffer(ele.files[0]);
}
```

More about the FileReader object:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: I tried that. I overrode the onload function. While this worked still to upload, it would quickly set the variable without having the whole file uploaded. I'll spend some more time looking into it again later

`$scope.readimg = function(ele) {
var r = new FileReader();
r.onload = function(e){
  $scope.image = e.target.result;
  ele.imgupload = false; 
}
ele.imgupload = true;
r.readAsArrayBuffer(ele.files[0]);
}`

Comment: how about r.onloadend? if everything fails I'd set an $interval for checkin FileReader.readyState. hope it doesn't come to that :]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11600171)

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin you are right. I updated the answer with the code in the comments (with some minor change).